# Member Reference base type 'Matrix(Vector &, Vector &) is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, matrix

When I attempt to use the void print function I receive the error "Member Reference base type 'Matrix(Vector &, Vector &) is not a structure or union". This program is supposed to take in values from the user and store them in the data array then it takes the Vector a and Vector b and does vector multiplication to print Matrix A.

```
    #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 const int rows=3;
 const int columns=3;
 const int elements=3;


 class Vector{
 private:
    double data[elements];
 public:
     Vector();
     void read();
     double get_element(int);
 };
 Vector::Vector(){
     int i=0;
     while(i<elements){data[i++]=0;}
 }
 Vector a;
 Vector b;
 Vector c;
 Vector d;
 void Vector::read(){
      int j=0;
      cout<<"Enter "<<elements<<" elements of vector a"<<endl;
     while(j<elements){cin>>data[j++];}


    }
    double Vector:: get_element(int n){
        while(n<elements)
            return data[n];

    }




    class Matrix {
            private:
                double data [rows*columns];
            public:
                Matrix(Vector &, Vector &);
                void add (const Matrix &);
                void mult (double);
                double trace();
                double norm();
                void print ();

    };

    Matrix::Matrix(Vector &, Vector &){
        int d,f;
                for (d=0; d<(rows); d++){
                    for (f=0; f<columns;f++){
                data[d*f]=a.get_element(d)*b.get_element(f);
    }
        }

    }
    Matrix A (Vector &a, Vector &b);
    Matrix B (Vector &c, Vector &d);

    void Matrix::print(){

        cout.precision(3);
                for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
                    cout << endl;
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
                cout << " " << data[i*j];
            }
        //This is printing Matrix A.
        }

    }

    int main(){
            a.read();
            b.read();
            c.read();
            d.read();
            A.print();
            //The error occurs here.
           return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Did you code this this way? Fix your indentation, please!

Comment: You declared A to be a function.

Comment: @David, indentation is the least of the problems here :X

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I couldn't see past the bad indentation to have even a chance of seeing those bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to define A and B as global variables, change 
`Matrix A (Vector &a, Vector &b);
    Matrix B (Vector &c, Vector &d);`

to `Matrix A (a, b);
    Matrix B (c, d);`

Comment: The `Matrix` constructor doesn't actually use its arguments

Comment: I'm supposed to combine Vector a and Vector b to form a Matrix object as an outer product and I don't know how to use them to make it work

Answer (score 0):

A and B are function names. The functions were declared as

```
   Matrix A (Vector &a, Vector &b);
   Matrix B (Vector &c, Vector &d);
```

in these declarations a and b are considered as function parameters.

So in this statement

```
A.print();
```

the compiler processes A as a function name.

I think you meant

```
   Matrix A (a, b);
   Matrix B (c, d);
```

EDIT: Here is an answer to your comment.

Class Vector has default constructor

```
 Vector::Vector(){
     int i=0;
     while(i<elements){data[i++]=0;}
 }
```

that sets all elements if data member data to zero.

You created objects of type Vector using the default constructor

```
 Vector a;
 Vector b;
 Vector c;
 Vector d;
```

and after that you created objects A and B of type Matrix using these Vectors.

```
Matrix A (a, b);
Matrix B (c, d);
```

So the objects contain zeroes.

You should remove these definitions and write in main

```
int main()
{
        Vector a, b, c, d;

        a.read();
        b.read();
        c.read();
        d.read();

        Matrix A( a, b );
        Matrix B( c, d );

        A.print();

        return 0;
}
```

By the way constructor

```
Matrix::Matrix(Vector &, Vector &){
    int d,f;
            for (d=0; d<(rows); d++){
                for (f=0; f<columns;f++){
            data[d*f]=a.get_element(d)*b.get_element(f);
}
    }
```

is invalid. It has two parameters but they are not used in the body of the constructor. Also local variables d and f are not initialized.

Comment: Ok that fixed that error but when the program runs and the user inputs the values for the vector the matrix prints all 0s.  I know my print function is wrong but not sure what to do.

Comment: I think these objects need to be outside of the main so that the overloaded Matrix constructor can use them because the constructor must combine Vector a and Vector b to form a Matrix object as an outer product. And do the same for Vector c and Vector d.

Comment: @user3413456 I am sorry I jave not understood what you said. Try the code I showed.

Comment: It won't compile because I'm using the objects outside the main in the Matrix constructor and print function.  I just don't know how to multiply the vectors to obtain the Matrix A in the overloaded constructor without using a.get_element(n)*b.get_element(n) for example.

Comment: @user3413456 Either you do as I said or do not write me your comments. If an error will occur then write me.

Comment: I did what you said and it didn't work then I did write you about what happened…

Comment: I know that I need to do what you said I just don't know how to incorporate it into the rest of the program so that it works.

Comment: You should change the `Matrix` constructor to use the arguments put in, insted of using global variables.

Comment: How can I change them from global variables?

Comment: @user3413456 Your constructor is invalid. See my updated post,